# Load a local bitmap over file:// in easeljs

Tags: google-chrome, cors, easeljs, createjs

I'm trying to add a local jpg to my canvas using easeljs with the following code:

```
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap('img/gallery/1.jpg');
stage.addChild(bitmap);
```

This puts the image on the canvas. I then want to add an onclick event to the image:

```
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap('img/gallery/1.jpg');
bitmap.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("CLICKED");
});
stage.addChild(bitmap);
```

This causes the following error:

```
Uncaught An error has occurred. This is most likely due to security restrictions on reading canvas pixel data with local or cross-domain images.
```

Obviously a cross origin type issue. I noticed the following in the easeljs docs:

```
Images loaded cross-origin will throw cross-origin security errors when interacted with using a mouse, using methods such as getObjectUnderPoint, or using filters, or caching. You can get around this by setting crossOrigin flags on your images before passing them to EaselJS, eg: img.crossOrigin="Anonymous";
```

I tried this (following the steps here [http://developers.spilgames.com/wiki/Developer_Platform_-_Learning_center_-*FAQ*-_HTML5_API_CreateJS_cross-domain_error](http://developers.spilgames.com/wiki/Developer_Platform_-_Learning_center_-_FAQ_-_HTML5_API_CreateJS_cross-domain_error)) and then got two errors:

```
Image from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
```

As the project I'm building is a Cordova/Phonegap project which needs to be able to run offline, getting the images from a web server is not possible, as far as I can see the images must come over file://. Does anybody have any ideas of how I can get around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided above from the error message? `You can get around this by setting crossOrigin flags on your images before passing them to EaselJS, eg: img.crossOrigin="Anonymous";`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent cross origin issues Chrome automatically blocks such images. **You can run it in Firefox** without causing the trouble.

In **order to test these in chrome** you have to run the file in **local server** like Apache tomcat.
Or use the running options run on server from **Web storm** like IDE.

If you don't have Web storm set up Apache tomcat server and copy your project folder in Apache tomcat/webapps folder. Now start the tomcat server, type `http://localhost:8080/pathto your project folder in webapps.`

ie if your project is in `../tomcat7/webapps/myproject/game.html`
type `http://localhost:8080/myproject/game.html`

Comment: There are lots of other options for local servers. MAMP (OSX), WAMP (Windows) are good for setting up profiles. IDEs like Codekit and Webstorm/PHPStorm can run local servers for testing as well. There is also a good one-liner on OS X: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

Comment: Yeah for sure . I told some solutions that i had used.

Answer (score 0):

Create a another Chrome shortcut and add `--disable-web-security` to the /chrome.exe schortcut link. Restart chrome using this link.